# Unable To Clone Azure DevOps Repo From VSOnline

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-devops, tfvc, azure-repos

I'm attempting to clone a repo into my workspace on Visual Studio Code Online (Chrome browser) using the Azure Repos extension (https://online.visualstudio.com/environments):

[image]

When I attempt to execute the `Team: Signin` command, I get the error:

[image]

When I attempt to clone the repo from the terminal I get:

```
vsonline:~/workspace$ git clone https://dev.azure.com/MyOrganization/MyProject/_git/MyApp
Cloning into 'MyAppApp'...
Username for 'https://dev.azure.com': myemail@mycompany.com
Password for 'https://myemail@mycompany.com@dev.azure.com': 
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://dev.azure.com/MyOrganization/MyProject/_git/MyApp'
```

I have this setup with no problem in VS Code on my desktop, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I have been working on this for several days and I finally managed to crack it. 1. select clone in vscode 2. it will ask you to open on new vscode window so click yes 3. head over to devOps and click on generate git credentials 4. copy the long password and paste it in upper password field prompt in vscode

this worked for me so well, happy coding?

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused by authentication when clone a repo from Azure DevOps Repos, it also led to your Azure Repos extension could not find a repo.

Please check [Authentication overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/auth-overview?view=azure-devops) and make sure the Username and Password are correct and workable.